# Buscar duas tabelas MySQL e selecionar linhas com um elemento em comum

Tags: php, mysql

Qual a maneira de usar um `foreach` para essa situação ?

Estaria selecionando um elemento da `tabela dois` - **evento** - e para cada evento, pegar da `tabela um` dados que também tenham em sua estrutura o mesmo evento.

Por sinal, ao fazer a pergunta vi nas relacionadas sobre `INNER JOIN`, seria esse um caminho ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Atualização - Agora deu certo! :)**

Primeiro foi alguns detalhes quanto a tabela HTML.

Estava usando `<thread>` mas é `<thead>` e o `<th>` do titulo fora de uma `<tr>` não funciona, passei a usar `<h>`.

Agora as mudanças que realmente importam pra lógica.

Troquei a estrutura do loop de fetch() para fetchAll(). A diferença é que antes estava criando uma array simples e não estava percorrendo todos elementos na hora de preencher as tabelas. Com o FetchAll eu passei todas as informações da tabela Ingressos em uma variável - Assim como no exemplo do @Paulo.

E a condição `If` agora funciona direitinho, pegando os eventos com nome iguais e fazendo o loop pra cada um.

`MySQL`

```
CREATE DATABASE Exercicio;

USE Exercicio;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eventos (
ID  SMALLINT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
evento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO eventos (evento) VALUES ('um');
INSERT INTO eventos (evento) VALUES ('dois');
INSERT INTO eventos (evento) VALUES ('tres');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingressos (
ID  SMALLINT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
mesa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
evento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('fulano', '30', 'um');
INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('fulana', '35', 'um');
INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('ciclano', '10', 'dois');
INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('ciclana', '31',  'dois');
INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('beltrano', '60', 'tres');
INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,mesa,evento) VALUES ('beltrana', '35', 'tres');
```

`HTML` e `PHP`

```html
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

$ingressos = $con->prepare("SELECT ingressos.nome, ingressos.mesa, ingressos.evento, eventos.evento FROM ingressos INNER JOIN eventos ON ingressos.evento = eventos.evento");
$ingressos ->execute();
$ingressos->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dados = $ingressos->fetchAll();


$eventos = $con->prepare("SELECT evento FROM eventos");
$eventos ->execute();

?>


<!doctype html>

<html>
 <body>
        
                <?php 

    if($ingressos){

        
            foreach($eventos as $evt){

echo " <div class='box[]'>
                       
       <table border='1px'>
         
         <thead>
                
                <h3> ".$evt['evento']."   </h3>
                
               <tr>
                         <th>mesa</th>
                         <th>nome</th>
               </tr> 
   
         </thead> ";

foreach($dados as $ingr){
    
    if($ingr['evento'] == $evt['evento']){
         
    echo " <tbody> ";
    echo " <tr>   ";                    
      
        
      echo "<td>" .$ingr['mesa'].   "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$ingr['nome'].   "</td>";
      
      
     
  }}}}
        
    echo " </tr>     ";                             
    echo " </tbody>  ";    
        
    echo " </table> ";                     
    echo "</div>";

?>



 </body>
</html>
```

Fui correndo no banco de dados acrescentar eventos na tabela Eventos e mais ingressos na tabela Ingressos e pronto, tudo indo pro seu caminho!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Existem inúmeras maneiras de usar o laço de repitação ForEach, como base na sua pergunta elaborei um exemplo simples para mostrar uso do Join e do Foreach.

Construção do banco (Note que usei os dados fornecido por você):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
CREATE TABLE Eventos(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Evento NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DataEvento DATETIME,
    Valor decimal
);


CREATE TABLE Controle(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Mesa INT NOT NULL,
    Cliente NVARCHAR(100),
    EventoID INT,

    CONSTRAINT FK_EventoDaMesa
    FOREIGN KEY (EventoID)
    REFERENCES Eventos.ID
);


INSERT INTO Eventos(Evento, DataEvento, Valor) VALUES('Evento A', '2018-02-23', 20.00);
INSERT INTO Eventos(Evento, DataEvento, Valor) VALUES('Evento B', '2018-02-21', 15.00);

INSERT INTO Controle(Mesa, Cliente, EventoID) VALUES(25, 'Cliente X', 1);
INSERT INTO Controle(Mesa, Cliente, EventoID) VALUES(40, 'Cliente X', 2);
INSERT INTO Controle(Mesa, Cliente, EventoID) VALUES(34, 'Cliente X', 1);
INSERT INTO Controle(Mesa, Cliente, EventoID) VALUES(55, 'Cliente X', 2);

SELECT C.Mesa, C.Cliente, E.Evento, E.DataEvento, E.Valor FROM Controle AS C
INNER JOIN Eventos AS E
ON C.ID = E.ID;
```

Uso do foreach no html + php (frisando existem varias maneiras):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
foreach($pdo->query($query) as $linha){
        echo("<table>
                <tr><th>$linha[2]</th></tr> 
                <tr><td>Mesa: $linha[0]</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cliente: $linha[1]</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data: $linha[3]</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Valor: $linha[4]</td></tr>
             </table");         
    }
```

---

Como solicitado uma tabela para cada evento (Só não entendi porque exibir uma coluna com nome do evento se o cabeçalho da tabela já informa de qual evento se trata):

**NOVA IMAGEM COM CORREÇÂO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou engatinhando no PHP e como não sou de "jogar a toalha", fiz uma pesquisa e vasculhando a documentação do PHP, encontrei um classe chamada `RecursiveIteratorIterator`... pesquisando mais fundo encontrei um exemplo onde essa classe era usada para incrementar linhas de uma tabela com o retorno da array gerada pela propriedade `Fetch`. Logo enxerguei as possibilidades. [Documentação PHP - Classe RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/it/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Espero ter ajudado a encontrar sua solução, pois estou super feliz com a descoberta dessa classe.

Como pode ver bem simples e funcional.
Não me preocupei em criar uma classe para conexão pois não foi solicitado conexão na questão.

Comment: você comentou dos outros usos do foreach, por acaso seria como se eu quisesse agrupar as linhas do mySQL de acordo com o evento em comum ? Refiz seu exemplo e o foreach acaba gerando uma tabela pra cada linha encontrada, tendo sempre Evento A ou Evento B se repetindo por exemplo, mas os dados são organizados corretos, única coisa é que não são agrupados na mesma tabela. Voltando ao seu exemplo, seria continuar imprimindo no Evento A o restante do seus INSERT, no caso do evento A teria tbm o cliente da mesa 34 por exemplo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Adicionei uma maneira que tentei fazer, não está como a sua, a estrutura do MySQL é outra, depois dê uma olhada se poder.

Comment: @Yemoja já vi sim, jájá posto como solicitado, é questão de lógica só!

Comment: @Yemoja Pronto cada tabela com seu dados respectivos.

Comment: Agradeço novamente @Paulo, mas ainda preciso rever algumas coisas... ainda não é o que imaginei, devo estar querendo trabalhar de forma errada com o banco de dados. A ideia era pegar esses dados da tabela ingresso e organizar numa página e separar em seus respectivos eventos. Eu coloquei a coluna Evento em ambas pra essa ser o elemento em comum. Porém, os eventos são cadastrados dinamicamente, essa é a necessidade do foreach - penso eu - pro php ver no MySQL quantas tabelas html vai ter que criar.

Comment: Bom dia @Yemoja - encontrei uma maneira e acho que agora você poderá solucionar o seu problema!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73239/discussion-between-yemoja-and-paulo-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas no php eu faria assim

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$evento = $_POST['evento'];

if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabelas_um WHERE evento = '$evento'")){
while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    //Aqui tu faz oq quer
     //Ex: imprimir os dados
       echo "Mesa: " . $row['mesa'] . " Nome: " . $row['nome'];

}
}else{
     echo "Nada encontrado!";
}
```

Como eu disse, não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas olhe se isto o satisfaz.

Comment: dê uma olhadada nas outras respostas, talvez vendo elas fique mais claro o que perguntei. Mas em suma seria gerar uma tabela pra cada evento e buscar no mysql os dados referente a cada evento. A questão é que tem 2 tabelas para se trabalhar.

Comment: para cada novo evento que você adicionasse na tabela principal você iria querer uma nova tabela somente para aquele evento? É isso?

Comment: E então depois ao escolher tão evento ele trouxesse os dados que estão na tabela do evento, certo?

Comment: Quanto a criação das tabelas `HTML` é exatamente isso, gerar uma pra cada evento registrado na tabela `MySQL` ( Tabela 2 ). E depois disso, a outra tabela `MySQL` ( Tabela 1 ) vai armazenar dados das pessoas, dizendo qual mesa e qual evento escolheram, e com esses dados serem impressos nas suas respectivas tabela `HTML`.

Comment: Acabei de colocar mais informações, inclusive o código.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer com `INNER JOIN` seria a forma mais clara e talvez performática para resolver este problema, a `query` seria mais ou menos isso:

```
SELECT b.* FROM `tabela_dois` a
INNER JOIN `tabela_um` b ON a.`evento` = b.`evento`;
```

Para fazer com `foreach` seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach ($tabelaDois as $linhaTabelaDois){
    foreach ($tabelaUM as $linhaTabelaUM){
        if ($linhaTabelaDois["evento"] == $linhaTabelaUM["evento"]){
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$linhaTabelaUM['mesa']."</td>
                    <td>".$linhaTabelaUM['nome']."</td>
                <tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: é por ai mesmo, comentei em outra resposta um outro "problema" que é a repetição das tabelas HTML, sendo que era pra cada evento ter sua tabela e seus dados.